# Smarty Templating-unable to get values from custom config file

Tags: php, configuration, smarty

I have built a custom smarty tpl file called logo.tpl.
Now,I want to modify logo.tpl(ojs/templates/common) file like below:

```
{config_load file='foo.conf'}
<div class="logo">
<img alt="logo" height="73" width="75" src="{$baseUrl}/images/logo.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="slogan">
 {$smarty.config.siteDesc}
</div>
```

and here is foo.conf

```
siteDesc = "blah blah blah"
```

The output what I can see from page source is:

```
<div class="logo">
<img alt="logo" height="73" width="75"
    src="http://localhost/ojs-2.3.7/images/logo.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="slogan">

</div>
```

So, though I am placing foo.conf in ojs/templates/common folder i.e. same folder as logo.tpl,the values are not getting reflected.

So any help in this regard would be appreciated.

Note:Details about OJS: http://pkp.sfu.ca/ojs/

**EDIT:**  This is solved by using {config_load file="core:common/foo.conf"} and placing foo.conf to lib\pkp\templates\common path. Thanks tpaksu.

Comment: maybe it's a path issue? is the file path relative to templates directory?

Comment: @tpaksu as I have mentioned,I placed both in same directory.

Comment: ok, but I'm still curious, did you try loading "common/foo.conf" ?

Comment: @tpaksu I have tried and getting same problem :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by using

```
{config_load file="core:common/foo.conf"}
<div class="logo">
<img alt="logo" height="73" width="75" src="{$baseUrl}/images/logo.jpg"/>
</div>
<div class="slogan">
{$smarty.config.siteDesc}
</div>
```

and placing foo.conf to lib\pkp\templates\common path. Thanks tpaksu.